# Ibus Unikey on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, ibus

After install ibus unikey, in my entry list didn't show Vietnamese (unikey), only show Vietnamese. Please help me!!!. I try reinstall all things related ibus, but it not work.

Comment: me too :(( can't do anything. Just waiting for update

Answer (score 1):

You should re-install `ibus`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ibus
```

After a clean install of 13.10, Ibus input sources were not showing up in the list of input sources in *Text Entry*. There were only keyboard layouts.

After reinstalling Ibus and rebooting, Ibus input methods were listed correctly in *Text Entry,* including `ibus-unikey`.

Comment: I try re-install all things related ibus, but it not work.

Comment: I saw that in your question, but assumed (incorrectly) that you meant the additional packages, not ibus itself. This took care of it for me. But not all ibus packages are working well under the new system (for example pinyin). So, I was able to install unikey after reinstalling ibus, and type a few letters with diacritics, but I don't know Vietnamese and can't say for sure unikey is working correctly. I'll look into it some more and edit the answer if I find anything else.

Comment: I try to install cinamon and can use ibus-unikey. May be waiting for ubuntu fix bug.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling ibus

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ibus
```

Closing your session  and login again, you will be able to add unikey among the typing methods